# return of ThreadPoolExecutor to array of tasks

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

Below is an  example code I got from https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/python-threadpoolexecutor-tutorial/

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import random

taskarr = []

def task(n,c):
    print("Executing our Task = {} and {}".format(n,c))
    print("Task Executed {}".format(threading.current_thread()))

def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    task1 = executor.submit(task(1,'A'))
    task2 = executor.submit(task(2,'B'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in this, if executor.submit is returned to simple variable task1, it works. But my requirement is to return it to an array. so when i do,
    taskarr[0] = executor.submit(task(1,'A'))
it throws error as,

```
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `taskarr[0] = executor.submit(task(1,'A'))` should trigger an  `IndexError`, the described `TypeError` will be raised if you did `task[0] = executor.submit(task(1,'A')) ` . Why don't you use `taskarr.append`?

Comment: this helped me in this regard: https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce your `TypeError`; apparently you have some more code that you did not show us. As rocksportrocker pointed out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314735/return-of-threadpoolexecutor-to-array-of-tasks#comment91577232_52314735), you can't assign values to an index that does not yet exist, as in your attempt to assign the future returned from `executor.submit()` to index 0 of the empty list `typearr`. This will raise the mentioned `IndexError`.

However, I could produce some `TypeError` and that is due to the fact that you call `submit` incorrectly.

The [Executor documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) defines the parameter `fn` to be a callable object, e.g. a function. Now, when you call `submit` like you do:

```
executor.submit(task(1,'A'))
```

`task(1,'A')` is executed in your main thread and its return value (`None` in your case) is then passed to the pool thread. The pool thread then tries to execute `None(1, 'A')` and raises a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, which you don't see, because it is wrapped in the future. You would see it if you called `task1.result()`.

That means, that it is your main thread that executes your task instead of your pool threads, as should have become visible from your second print statement in `task`:

```
Task Executed <_MainThread(MainThread, started 11064)>
```

In order to have your pool threads do the work, you need to pass the function object `task` to `executor.submit`, like so:

```
taskarr = []

def task(n,c):
    print("Executing our Task = {} and {}".format(n,c))
    time.sleep(3)  # added this to make sure that two different threads from the pool get a task
    print("Task Executed {}".format(threading.current_thread()))

def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    taskarr.append(executor.submit(task, 1,'A'))
    taskarr.append(executor.submit(task, 2,'B'))
    # to show that the main thread continues to execute
    # while the pool threads work on the tasks
    print("{}: tasks submitted".format(threading.current_thread().name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Executing our Task = 1 and A
Executing our Task = 2 and B
MainThread: tasks submitted
Task Executed <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 12192)>
Task Executed <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 11800)>
```

Comment: Love: "you can't assign values to an index that does not yet exist"
With so many of python's features allowing you to just start using variables without declaring them it must be a real shock that containers like lists have this kind of behaviour.